# Get touch events at 1 second intervals on javascript

Tags: javascript

I am building a touch responsive website using some javascript.  I need to get the x-coordinate of a finger touch as it slides across the screen.

I have tried the touchmove event, but it polls way too frequently for what I intend to use it for.  Is there a way to slow down how often touchmove updates?  Or is there a way to manually grab the x-coordinate of a touch and slide at 1 second intervals?  I've been banging my head against the wall for awhile and haven't found anything useful online yet.

To be clear, I think all I need is the pageX property of a touch event at 1 second intervals.

Comment: Put the `pageX` to an external variable in a touchmove handler, and use interval to read it?

Comment: @Teemu thanks, that was the hint that I needed.